# How to specify distance between nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to specify a distance for `right of`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, 
    text  width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{rq} = [block, text  width=12em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
 \node [block] (f) {A1. First};

 \node[block, below of = f] (s) {A2. Second};

 \node[rq, right = 5cm of=f] (r1) {RQ1. Some\\ RQ2. Questions};

\path [line] (f) -- node {} (r1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

but I get

> Package PGF Math error unkown operator `o' or`of'

It seems like I am not loading `positioning` correctly!?

Comment: Use `below = of f` and `right = 5cm of f`, respectively.

Comment: Any news? Does Oleinik's comment solve your problem?